# Is the definability of an elementary embedding needed to show that we have an $M-$ultrafilter?

Tags: set-theory

So there is an exercise in Kanamori's The Higher Infinite which I have solved partially but I think it needs some hypothesis to fully prove it. Let me give some context.

---

Throughout this post assume that $M$ and $N$ are transitive models of $\text{ZFC}^{-}$. Meaning they model ZFC minus the Powerset Axiom.

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal in the sense of $M$ and $U$ a set in $V$. Then $U$ is called an $M-\text{ultrafilter}$ on $\kappa$ iff
$$ \langle M, \in, U\rangle \models U \text{ is a normal ultrafilter over } \kappa; \text{ and}$$
$$ \langle M, U \rangle \text{ is weakly amenable: for any } F \in {^\kappa M} \cap M, \{ \xi \lt \kappa \mid F(\xi) \in U \} \in M.$$

Now here is the statement of the exercise:

Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are transitive models of $\text{ZFC}^{-}$, $k: M \prec N$ with $\operatorname{crit}(k) = \kappa$, and $P(\kappa)\cap M = P(\kappa)\cap N$. Then 
$$ \{ X \in P(\kappa)\cap M \mid \kappa \in k(X)\} $$
is an $M-\text{ultrafilter}$ over $\kappa$.

---

Now checking the parts related to the fact that this set is a normal ultrafilter in $M$ weren't that hard. The tricky part for me was to show the weak amenability part.

So I let $F \in {^\kappa M} \cap M$ and $U = \{ X \in P(\kappa)\cap M \mid \kappa \in k(X)\}$ and I had to show that $\{ \xi \lt \kappa \mid F(\xi) \in U \}$ is in $M$. But the only thing that came to my mind was that:
$$\{ \xi \lt \kappa \mid F(\xi) \in U \} = \{ \xi \lt \kappa \mid \kappa \in k(F(\xi))\},$$
And if $k$ is definable in $M$, we are done by separation.

And I can't come up with any other method. Do we need the definability of $k$ in $M$, or is this true regardless?

---

EDIT I:

Now that I have had more time to think on it, I had an idea, but it's still not complete.

So I want to use $k(F):k(\kappa) \rightarrow N$ as a function in $N$. Now if I prove that for $\xi \lt \kappa$, $k(F)(\xi) = k(F(\xi))$, then:

$$ \{ \xi \lt \kappa \mid \kappa \in k(F)(\xi) \} = \{ \xi \lt \kappa \mid \kappa \in k(F(\xi))\}$$

But here the lhs is in $N$ by separation because $k(F)$ is just a function in $N$ and because of $P(\kappa) \cap M = P(\kappa) \cap N$, we are done.

So my question reduces to the following:

How can I prove that $k(F)(\xi) = k(F(\xi))$, for $\xi \lt \kappa$?
I can show such a statement for regular ultrapower embeddings using the constant functions and such, but here I guess I should use elementarity in some way?

Comment: Try proving that $k(F(\xi))=k(F)(k(\xi))$, and use the fact that $\xi<\kappa$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I think I got it now: First we have that $M \models \forall X[ X = F(\xi) \leftrightarrow (\xi, X) \in F]$. Now by elementarity we have that $N \models \forall X[ X = k(F(\xi)) \leftrightarrow (k(\xi), X) \in k(F)]$. But $k(F)(k(\xi))$ is an $X$ that satisfies the rhs, so we must have that $k(F)(k(\xi)) = k(F(\xi))$ and also $k(\xi) = \xi$, since $\xi \lt \operatorname{crit}(k) = \kappa$. Right?

Comment: Yes, also possible is the observation that $k(F)$ is a function, and that $(k(\xi),k(X))\in k(F)$ since $(\xi,X)\in F$. So $k(X)=k(F(X))=k(F)(k(\xi))$.

Comment: I guess in general I can prove that for any arbitrary relation or function like $R(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ which lives in $M$, we have the same deal. Or maybe any definable relation or function. Many thanks for the hint.

Comment: You're very welcome. Keep up the good work.